# nohup/cron/screen - Running script in backgroud - better option?

Tags: php, ssh, cron, gnu-screen, nohup

I have a PHP script which has a forever loop

```
<?php
    while(1)
        {
             //Do something 
        }
?>
```

I need to run this script such that, even if I close my SSH session, it should always be running in the background. I know of cronjob, but cronjob will interrupt my script every 1 hour, for example. I want the script to be always running and not at specific times.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? (Its an Apache server running on Ubuntu)

**Edit**

Thanks to the commnets-

Now I have 3 options -

1) `nohup php filename.php &`

2) `screen php filename.php`

3) Doing something like this using cronjob http://reviewsignal.com/blog/2013/08/22/long-running-processes-in-php/

Can anyone tell me which is a better option? I want such that, even if an error occurs or it may be killed, or it may crash for some reason, the script should restart itself.

Comment: You run it from the command line or as a service. `/usr/bin/php -f myscript.php` for example.

Comment: Performing cronjob every minute seems a better solution. While maximum execution time for cronjob by default is 180 seconds, which is still greater than 1 minute, so technically speaking, its running continuously.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Will this run my script even I close the SSH terminal?

Comment: @Manikiran I do not want to interrupt my script. If I use cronJob, it will start my script ever minute, won't it?

Comment: No it wont work for you

Comment: @Blueblazer172 What wont work ?

Comment: Running the script when you delete your ssh session. It only works if you use cronjobs

Comment: You start something from the command line and it will continue to run even after you exit your SSH session. You can also use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to run your item as a service which is the best way to go on Linux systems.

Comment: You should look into something like supervisord: That can start your process and restart it if something happens to it (code problem / exception, server reboot, etc.)

Comment: @Blueblazer172 you can start a job from the command line in the background and it will continue to run after you exit the SSH session.

Comment: `nohup php script.php &`, but you should check if the script is running, as it may be killed, or it may crash for some reason. And this is actually a difficult problem. So there are too many possible answers.

Comment: http://reviewsignal.com/blog/2013/08/22/long-running-processes-in-php/ How about this solution?

Comment: You want to *daemonize* your script, for which there are many possibilities. Look at the (new) duplicate.

Comment: @deceze as Ruslan says in the comments  - `nohup php script.php &, but you should check if the script is running, as it may be killed, or it may crash for some reason` using nohup I'll have to check myself if the script is running. Which I dont want to..

Comment: Read more than just the first answer. There are a ton of methods listed to create a startup service from any command line program.

Comment: @deceze I only read `nohup php filename.php &` as all the answers